# Identificar numero no array e alterar para uma string

Tags: array, ruby

Estou tentando trocar números divisíveis por 3 por uma palavra dentro do meu `array`. Tentei acrescentar meu `if` dentro do `array` e sem resultado.

```
def code( n )
    if n % 3 == 0
    Array.new(n + 1) { |i| i }  
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não tá informando a palavra a ser trocada nos parametros
Você precisa de um `Array` com uma tamanho `size` e a palavra (`word`) que vai substituir os multiplos de 3.

```
def code(size, word)
  Array.new(size + 1) { |i| i % 3 == 0 ? word : i }  
end
```

*Resultado*

> > code(10, 'ruby')

```
 ["ruby", 1, 2, "ruby", 4, 5, "ruby", 7, 8, "ruby", 10]
```

#### editando (outro exemplo)

```
minha_palavra = 'joão'
code(10, minha_palavra)
```

resultado

```
["joão", 1, 2, "joão", 4, 5, "joão", 7, 8, "joão", 10]
```

Dica é uma boa prática dar melhores noves para suas varáveis, em vez de usar `code(n)` tente user `code(tamanho)` ou `code(size)` assim quando você lê vc já sabe o que está passando.

Comment: Entendi ! Aonde que eu declaro então pra substituir por pela palavra "ruby" no caso ? Tentei aqui mas me informou um erro dizendo 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)"

Comment: Exemplo code(10, 'palavra que vc quiser'). Pega o código que coloquei acima e muda o segundo parametro.

Comment: Colocando depois de word, assim > word: code(10, 'Ruby')? Desculpe as perguntas, ainda sou novo em Ruby

Comment: word: code(10, 'Ruby') tá errado! o certo é executar somente o código a seguir code(10, 'qualquer_palatra')            --adicionei mais uma descrição lá em cima

Comment: Eu entendi como você fez ! Mas não está indo, me retorna erro. Setei direto dentro do Array. Queria que ele verificasse sozinho e alterasse, como você fez.